# Why is my RPC returning a String thats crashing my Application?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I've tried to cut my code down to the bare bones:

Here is my Server Code

```
public String updateContact(Long AdminID, Long ID,
     String Name,String Phone,
     String KnownAs, String Notes) throws NotLoggedInException {
    {
      String ReturnName="Server NAME";
      LOG.log(Level.WARNING, "updateContact returning:'"+ReturnName+"'");
      return(ReturnName);
    }
```

Here is my Client Code

```
LogMe(2,"JVD20130217 BEFORE UpdateContact");
ContactService.updateContact(CompanyInfo.getID(), CurrentContactID,
       CurrentContact.getName(), CurrentContact.getPhone(),
       CurrentContact.getKnownAs(), CurrentContact.getNotes(),
       new AsyncCallback<String>()
            {
              public void onFailure(Throwable error)
              {
                LogMe(2,"FAILED UpdateContact");
              }
              public void onSuccess(String NewNamex)
              {
                LogMe(2,"a SUCCESS UpdateContact");
                LogMe(2,"b UpdateContact:"+ "NewNamex: '" + NewNamex+"'");
              }
          });
          LogMe(2,"JVD20130217 AFTER UpdateContact");
```

Heres the output Log:

```
2: JVD20130217 BEFORE UpdateContact
2: JVD20130217 AFTER UpdateContact
```

So as you can see it never appears to return from the RPC call, HOWEVER the server logs are as follows:

```
18-Feb-2013 01:49:15 com.diarybooker.server.ContactServiceImpl updateContact
WARNING: updateContact returning:'Server JOHN'
```

So it looks like its returning OK....

Anyone got any ideas what I can do to investigate further? Or better yet, give me any idea whats wrong!!

Comment: Not sure about why you're seeing a problem, but you might want to try something like Fiddler2 to see what's going over the wire

Comment: Im using Chrome Inspector, which showed everything was OK. Oddly since writing the question it suddenly seemed to start working again for no obviously good reason... Im building line by line to see if i can recreate it again!!!